# How to remove some unnecessary spaces in json file?

Tags: jquery, json, node.js

I am newbie to this json and node.js. Now i have json file in that some unnecessary spaces are there. How to remove that?

### .json file

```
{
"Product_Name": "Logitech M235 Wireless Mouse (Red)",
"Brand": "Logitech",
"Color": "\n            \n                Red\n            \n        ",
"Image": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31UXrp3AcLL._SY300_QL70_.jpg",
"Price": "   699.00",
"Rating": "4.4 out of 5 stars"
}
```

The color value contain some spaces, i don't want that spaces i need only 'Red'.

Here i am writing to json file

### server.js

```
var json = {Product_Name : "", Brand : "", Color : "", Image : "", Price : "", Rating : ""};
            
        var P_name = $('#title').children().text();
        var brand = $('#brand').text();
        var color = $('.a-row').find('span.selection').text();
        var price = $('#price').find('span.a-size-medium').text();
        var rating = $('#averageCustomerReviews').find('span.a-icon-alt').text();
        var image = $('.imgTagWrapper').children().attr('src');
            
        json.Product_Name = P_name;
        json.Brand = brand;
        json.Color = color;
        json.Price = price;
        json.Rating = rating;
        json.Image = image;
            
        fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err){
            console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace whitespace and newline in string in color variable like this

```
color.trim()
```

Comment: The trim is being called in nodejs so is valid

Comment: No worries easy mistake to make

Comment: Thank you @simon-p-r. I fixed that problem using your answer.